# Get the X-API-KEY value from header in Phil Sturgeon REST API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

I have made an API using Phil Sturgeon REST Api which uses the codeignitor framework.
Every request made to my api should have X-API-KEY:{api key} in the request header.
Is there anyway I can get the api key of a request so that the api can identify the user who has generated the api key in my system.Is there anyway I get get the X-API-KEY value from the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@piya I am not sure this could help you out or not.. but give it a try..

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value)
{
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in CodeIgniter to get header specific key value

```
$key_value = $this->input->get_request_header("X-API-KEY");
```

from CodeIgniter documentation here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get_request_header

Answer (score 1):

Try $_SERVER['HTTP_X_API_KEY']..

```
$key_name = 'HTTP_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', $api_key_variable));
```

The above is how the REST_Controller finds out the key from the request headers.